# AKKA HTTP Source Streaming with Futures

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a large video file sharded in a Cassandra table. I am trying stream it back to the API client, by using `Source` streaming.

My service code looks like below,

```
def getShards(id: String, shards: Int) = {
  def getShardsInternal(shardNo: Int, shards: Future[Array[Byte]]): Future[Array[Byte]] = {
    if (shardNo == 0) shards
    else getShardsInternal(shardNo - 1, shards.flatMap(x => Database.ShardModel.find(id, shardNo)))
  }
  getShardsInternal(shards, Future.successful(Array()))
}
```

In my AKKA HTTP route, I try to build a `Source` from the returned future, as shown below,

```
def getAsset = get {
  pathPrefix("asset") {
    parameters('id) { id =>
      complete {
        val f = mediaService.getMetadata(id).flatMap { x =>
          mediaService.getShards(id, x.shards)
        }
        Source.fromFuture(f)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how `Source.fromFuture` gets committed to the response. The future that is passed is essentially a series of flat-mapped futures expected to execute sequentially. However, I don't believe this will go back as a chunked byte stream back to the client.

Any pointers on this will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
I have been trying to narrow this down further with the following,

```
get {
  pathPrefix("asset") {
    parameters('id) { id =>
      complete {
        Source.fromFuture {
          Future.successful("Hello".getBytes()).flatMap(x => Future.successful("World".getBytes()))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting this to return

```
[72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100]
```

However, I only get the result of the last future as below,

```
[[87,111,114,108,100]]
```

Kind regards
Meeraj

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `Source[Array[Byte], NotUsed]` to a `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`, and use [`HttpEntity`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity$.html#apply(contentType:akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType,data:akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,Any]):akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Chunked) with [`ContentTypes`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/ContentTypes$.html):

```
import akka.util.ByteString

def getAsset = get {
  pathPrefix("asset") {
    parameters('id) { id =>
      val f = mediaService.getMetadata(id).flatMap { x =>
        mediaService.getShards(id, x.shards)
      }
      val source = Source.fromFuture(f).map(ByteString.apply)
      complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, source))
    }
  }
}
```

Here I'm using `application/octet-stream` as an example. Since you're streaming a video, you might need to use [`ContentType.Binary`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/ContentType$$Binary.html) with an appropriate [media type](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/MediaTypes$.html). For example:

```
complete(HttpEntity(ContentType.Binary(MediaTypes.`video/mpeg`), source))
```

---

Addressing your comment and update, it appears that you want to concatenate the results of the Futures in `getShards`: as you've discovered, `flatMap` doesn't do that. Use `Future.reduceLeft` instead:

```
def getShards(id: String, shards: Int): Future[Array[Byte]] = {
  val futures = (1 to shards).map(Database.ShardModel.find(id, _))
  Future.reduceLeft(futures)(_ ++ _)
}
```

Alternatively, instead of concatenating the results into a single array, you could redefine `getShards` to return a `Future[List[Array[Byte]]]`, then create a `Source` using `flatMapConcat`:

```
def getShards(id: String, shards: Int): Future[List[Array[Byte]]] = {
  val futures = (1 to shards).map(Database.ShardModel.find(id, _)).toList
  Future.sequence(futures)
}

def getAsset = get {
  pathPrefix("asset") {
    parameters('id) { id =>
      val f = mediaService.getMetadata(id).flatMap { x =>
        mediaService.getShards(id, x.shards)
      }
      val source =
        Source.fromFuture(f)
              .flatMapConcat(Source.apply)
              .map(ByteString.apply)
      complete(HttpEntity(/* a content type */, source))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be only sending the result of the last future to the client.

Comment: @Meeraj: Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to have done the trick. BTW method on Future seems to reduce rather than reduceLeft. Also, is the reduce operation (++) going to be lazy or is the byte array for the entire video going to be materialized in memory before committed to the response. What I am trying to achieve is chunk the byte array for each shard into the response stream. I found the link below,

Comment: https://jonas.github.io/akka-http/paradox-theme-akka/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html#implementing-custom-entitystreamingsupport-traits

Comment: @Meeraj: Updated again.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through the update. Even though the original suggestion worked, I am not sure it streamed, as the reduce operation on the future would have materialized the whole byte array in memory.

Comment: Thanks again. I think flatMapConcat is the right solution. For some reason, the byte stream that gets eventually produced seems to be corrupted. I need to dig into see what is going wrong.

Comment: Found the problem, I need to reverse the list in getShards. Look, your responses have been absolutely phenomenal. Many thanks and really appreciate it. I need a lot more reading up needed on AKKA Streams :)